# Efficient todo / project / task manager application

Tags: software-rec, free-software

I am looking at a *todo / project / task management* application for Linux that goes beyond making a simple list of tasks with check boxes.

What I'm looking for is an application that will also allow me to follow up on tasks (for examples *task T = "send an email to John"*), when complete it should also follow up on a response from John.

It should also help me organising tasks in different projects.

The only applications I found so far are so so and do not really improve upon the simple pen and paper list.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can wholeheartedly recommend [**Getting Things GNOME!**](http://gtgnome.net/).
Its design philosophy is based on [David Allen’s work "Getting Things Done: The Art of Stress-Free Productivity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done). Don’t be misled by its name; it works equally fine with desktop environments other than GNOME. For example, I use it with [XFCE](http://www.xfce.org/).

Apart from the [project homepage](http://gtgnome.net/), you will also find useful information about `gtg` over at the [dedicated GNOME wiki page](http://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/gtg). This includes [keyboard shortcuts](http://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gtg/documentation)
 and an explanation about [how the QuickAdd entry works](http://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gtg/documentation).

Furthermore, `gtg` saves all its data in [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)-formatted text files. Because of this wise design decision, [distributed revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) can easily be implemented. I did so with [Hg Mercurial](http://hginit.com/01.html). Now, I can access my task list from any system which does not necessarily need to be connected to the internet at all times. Synchronisation is eventually done over [SSH protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell), which guarantees privacy. Merges are handled automatically most of the time.

To get you up to speed with `hg`, here is a small collection of links to [more Mercurial tutorials](http://hamwaves.com/it/en/index.html). Of course, Mercurial becomes superfluous if `gtg` is used on a single client or LAN.

Finally, [**Getting Things GNOME!**](http://gtgnome.net/) is very easy to learn; it comes seeded with a concise self-contained tutorial in task form!

[image: gtg screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

[taskcoach](http://taskcoach.org/) is a GUI based todo manager that has had an active development for a long time.

If you are more into commandline and textfile base ToDo list look at [todo.txt](http://todotxt.com/)
(it has some applications that handle the format as well).

Answer (score 0):

**[TracWiki: Project Management System](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWiki)**

TracWiki is a light-weight project management wiki-portal which runs over HTTP ports.

[image]

**[Install Guide](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall)**

- Light-Weight
- Easy Setup
- Modular (Multiple Projects)
- Hot-Copy Backups On-The-Fly
- Non-Invasive (Standard Wiki Formatting, similar to StackExchange Markup)
- Tickets
- Tasks
- Road-Maps
- Mile-Stones

**Install Guide derived from Link to Install Guide**

**Package Dependencies:**

- Python, greater than or equal to v.2.5 and less than v.3.0 (2.5, 2.6, or 2.7)
- [PySQLITE](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite)

  $ tar xvfz .tar.gz
  $ cd 
  $ python setup.py build_static install
- setuptools, version greater than or equal to v.0.6
- Genshi, version greater than or equal to 0.6

**Setting Project Directory**

```
$ trac-admin /path/to/my/project initenv
```

**Running the Stand-Alone Server**

```
$ tracd --port 8000 /path/to/my/project
```

**Running the Stand-Alone Server with Authentication**

```
$ tracd -p 8000 --basic-auth="myprojectname,/path/to/my/project/.htpasswd,myprojectname" /path/to/my/project
```

**Generate .htpasswd Files**

[Use This Tool to Generate your User and Password for the .htpasswd File.](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)